# confusing behavior with case and isnumeric

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my stored procedure I have a case statement that is supposed to test whether a field is numeric and handle that but I get the same error no matter what. I have tried below:

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(subScores.ScoreValue) = 1 THEN CAST(subScores.ScoreValue AS REAL) ELSE -1 END
```

I also used a custom convert function because I have read that isnumeric isn't 100% reliable but that received the same error. I also tried using `CONVERT` but no success there. I even replaced the isnumeric with `0=1` which should always fail but I still get the same error which I find really strange. This is my error:

```
Error converting data type nvarchar to real
```

The values that it is checking look like:

```
A0, A10, A23, B9, B51, C90, C100, etc
```

Any ideas for this behavior?
Here is the full procedure. The issue happening on the first case in the where clause after the `THEN` instead of using -1 its using the actual field. It also contain my usage of ISNUMERIC and my custom function:

```
@strDemoCodeIds             nvarchar(100),
        @strYearIds                 nvarchar(100),
        @intRosterSetId             int,
        @intSchoolId                int,
        @intTeachId                 int,
        @intGradeId                 int,
        @intDeptId                  int,
        @intCourseId                int,
        @intPeriodId                int,
        @strTestInstIds             nvarchar(100),
        @intTestTypeId              int,
        @intSubjectId               int,
        @intScoreTypeId             int,
        @strSuppScoreTypeId         nvarchar(20),
        @intClusterScoreTypeId      int,
        @intClusterColorScoreTypeId int,
        @intLocalReportId           int,    
        @strSortMethod              nvarchar(20),
        @intAnchorYear              int     


       AS
       BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @topYearID INT

        DECLARE @subs TABLE (subId int)
        IF @intSubjectId < 100
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @subs
                    SELECT MM_Test_Subjects.pkTestSubjectID 
                    FROM MM_Test_Subjects 
                    WHERE MM_Test_Subjects.fkCSTStrandID = @intSubjectId
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @subs VALUES (@intSubjectId)
            END

        DECLARE @years TABLE (yearId int)
        INSERT INTO @years
            SELECT number FROM itot(@strYearIds, N',')

        SET @topYearID = @intAnchorYear

        SELECT  s.pkStudentID,
                s.LastName,
                s.FirstName,
                s.StudentNumber,
                st.fkTestInstanceID,
                bands.Description AS 'PL',
                bands.Color,
                subScoresSupp.scoreValue AS 'SuppScore',
                clusters.pkTestClusterID,
                clusterScores.ScoreValue,
                colors.ScoreValue,
                ti.TestInstanceName,
                tp.TestPeriodTitle,
                subScores.ScoreValue AS 'PLScore',
                ScoreType.pkScoreTypeID,
                bands.StackPosition AS 'StackPosition'
        FROM Students s
        INNER JOIN StudentTests st ON s.pkStudentID = st.fkStudentID
        INNER JOIN StudentTests baseSt ON s.pkStudentID = baseSt.fkStudentID
            AND baseSt.fkGradeID = CASE @intGradeId WHEN 99 THEN baseSt.fkGradeID ELSE @intGradeId END
            AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM StudentScores_Subject baseSubScores WHERE baseSubScores.fkStudentTestID = baseSt.pkStudentTestID
                            AND baseSubScores.fkTest_SubjectID IN (SELECT subId FROM @subs)
                            AND baseSubScores.fkScoreTypeID = @intScoreTypeId)
        INNER JOIN StudentTestDemographics d ON d.fkStudentTestID = baseSt.pkStudentTestID
        INNER JOIN itot(@strDemoCodeIds, N',') tblDemoCodes ON d.fkDemographicCodeID = CASE @strDemoCodeIds WHEN '0' THEN d.fkDemographicCodeID ELSE tblDemoCodes.number END                
        INNER JOIN StudentScores_Subject subScores ON subScores.fkStudentTestID = st.pkStudentTestID 
            AND subScores.fkTest_SubjectID IN (SELECT subId FROM @subs)
            AND subScores.fkScoreTypeID = @intScoreTypeId
        LEFT JOIN PerformanceLevelReportBands bands ON bands.fkPerformanceLevelReportID = @intLocalReportId
        LEFT JOIN MMARS_Web_TestInfo_California.dbo.PerfLevelReportBandCutScores cutScores ON cutScores.fkPerformanceLevelReportBandID = bands.pkPerformanceLevelReportBandID
            AND cutScores.fkGradeID = @intGradeId
            AND cutScores.fkTestSubjectID IN (SELECT subId FROM @subs)
        RIGHT JOIN PerfLevelReportBandComponents bandComponents ON bandComponents.fkPerformanceLevelReportBandID = bands.pkPerformanceLevelReportBandID 
        LEFT JOIN StudentScores_Subject subScoresSupp ON subScoresSupp.fkStudentTestID = st.pkStudentTestID
            AND subScoresSupp.fkTest_SubjectID IN (SELECT subId FROM @subs)
            AND subScoresSupp.fkScoreTypeID IN (SELECT tblsubScoresSupp.number FROM itot(@strSuppScoreTypeId, N',') tblsubScoresSupp)
        LEFT JOIN MM_ScoreTypes ScoreType ON ScoreType.pkScoreTypeID = subScoresSupp.fkScoreTypeID  
        LEFT JOIN StudentScores_Cluster clusterScores ON clusterScores.fkStudentTestID = st.pkStudentTestID
            AND clusterScores.fkTest_SubjectID IN (SELECT subId FROM @subs)
            AND clusterScores.fkScoreTypeID = @intClusterScoreTypeId
        LEFT JOIN StudentScores_Cluster colors ON colors.fkStudentTestID = st.pkStudentTestID
            AND colors.fkTest_SubjectID IN (SELECT subId FROM @subs)
            AND colors.fkScoreTypeID = @intClusterColorScoreTypeId
            AND colors.fkTest_ClusterID = clusterScores.fkTest_ClusterID
        LEFT JOIN MM_Test_Clusters clusters ON clusters.pkTestClusterID = clusterScores.fkTest_ClusterID
        INNER JOIN TestInstances ti ON ti.pkTestInstanceID = st.fkTestInstanceID
        INNER JOIN TestInstances baseTi ON baseTi.pkTestInstanceID = baseSt.fkTestInstanceID
            AND baseTi.fkSchoolYearID = @topYearID
        INNER JOIN CAHSEE_TestPeriods tp on tp.pkTestPeriodID = ti.fkTestPeriodID
        INNER JOIN CAHSEE_TestPeriods baseTp on baseTp.pkTestPeriodID = baseTi.fkTestPeriodID
        INNER JOIN Roster_Students rs ON rs.fkStudentID = s.pkStudentID
        INNER JOIN Roster_Groups rg ON rg.fkTestInstanceID = baseTi.pkTestInstanceID
            AND ti.pkTestInstanceID IN (SELECT tblTestInstances.number FROM itot(@strTestInstIds, N',') tblTestInstances)
            AND baseTi.pkTestInstanceID IN (SELECT tblTestInstances.number FROM itot(@strTestInstIds, N',') tblTestInstances)
            AND rg.fkRosterSetID = @intRosterSetId
            AND rg.pkRosterGroupID = rs.fkRosterGroupID
            AND (rg.fkSchoolID = @intSchoolId OR @intSchoolId = 0)
            AND (rg.fkTeacherID = @intTeachId OR @intTeachId = 0)
            AND (rg.fkGradeID = baseSt.fkGradeID)
            AND (rg.fkDepartmentID = @intDeptId OR @intDeptId = 0)
            AND (rg.fkCourseID = @intCourseId OR @intCourseId = 0)
            AND (rg.fkPeriodID = @intPeriodId OR @intPeriodId = 0)
        WHERE (bandComponents.ScoreValue = subScores.ScoreValue)
            OR 
            ((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(subScores.ScoreValue) = 1 THEN CAST(subScores.ScoreValue AS REAL) ELSE subScores.ScoreValue END)
                BETWEEN (CASE WHEN dbo.TryConvertInt(bandComponents.minScore) = 1 THEN CAST(bandComponents.minScore AS REAL) ELSE bandComponents.minScore END) and 
                (CASE WHEN dbo.TryConvertInt(bandComponents.maxScore) = 1 THEN CAST(bandComponents.maxScore AS REAL) ELSE bandComponents.maxScore END)/*CAST(ISNULL(bandComponents.maxScore,'0') AS INT)*/)
            OR 
            ((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(subScores.ScoreValue) = 1 THEN CAST(subScores.ScoreValue AS REAL) ELSE -1 END)
                BETWEEN ISNULL(cutScores.minScore,0) and ISNULL(cutScores.maxScore,0))
        GROUP BY s.pkStudentID, s.LastName, s.FirstName, s.StudentNumber, st.fkTestInstanceID, bands.Description, bands.Color, subScoresSupp.scoreValue, 
            clusters.pkTestClusterID, clusterScores.ScoreValue, colors.ScoreValue, ti.TestInstanceName, tp.TestPeriodTitle, subScores.ScoreValue, 
            ScoreType.pkScoreTypeID, bands.StackPosition
        ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN @strSortMethod = 'ScoreDesc'
                THEN bands.StackPosition END DESC,
            CASE WHEN @strSortMethod = 'ScoreAsc'
                THEN bands.StackPosition END ASC,
            CASE WHEN @strSortMethod = 'ScoreDesc' AND ISNUMERIC(subScores.ScoreValue) = 1
                THEN CONVERT(int, subScores.ScoreValue) END DESC,
            CASE WHEN @strSortMethod = 'ScoreAsc' AND ISNUMERIC(subScores.ScoreValue) = 1
                THEN CONVERT(int, subScores.ScoreValue) END ASC,
                s.LastName, s.FirstName, s.pkStudentID, st.fkTestInstanceID


   END
```

Comment: Isnumeric function has been working given error of converting of real means the value of scorevalue is not converting in real

Comment: @MukeshKalgude I don't understand it shouldn't be casting as real because ISNUMERIC should not be passing but it is. A15 for example is NOT numeric.

Comment: Show the whole query that the CASE is part of. The snippet you have supplied is incomplete.

Comment: @JohnS Added the full proc

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the case statement is trying to return only one type of value so if the `THEN` is trying to convert to real and return that back then the `ELSE` is going to try and do the same so even if there is no cast it is going to try to convert it implicitly. This explains why this works:

```
DECLARE @scoreValue nvarchar(10)
SET @scoreValue = N'A53'
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@scoreValue) = 1 THEN CAST(@scoreValue AS REAL) ELSE 1.0 END
```

But this does not:

```
DECLARE @scoreValue nvarchar(10)
SET @scoreValue = N'A53'
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@scoreValue) = 1 THEN CAST(@scoreValue AS REAL) ELSE @scoreValue END
```

So the key is to use `sql_variant` so this works:

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@scoreValue) = 1 THEN CAST(@scoreValue AS REAL) ELSE CAST(@scoreValue AS sql_variant) END
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try for your stuff then find this iss

```
select CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(CONVERT(nvarchar,'- 5')) = 1 THEN CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar,'- 5') AS REAL) ELSE -1 END
```

Isnumeric function should be return of this value true, and convert function should not convert value into real because space in value.

find data of this type in your column like scorevalue.

Comment: There are no spaces for any values in the scorevalue column if thats what you are saying?

Comment: @Rdawg I think check "$" contains record like "$4". isnumeric function return true and converting given error

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Show how isnumeric differs from TRY_CONVERT*/
declare @temp table (dec int, chr char(1) , isnum int,tryconvert int)
declare @loop int = 1
declare @i int
while @loop < 127
begin
    set @i = @loop
    insert into @temp (dec,chr,isnum,tryconvert)
    select @i,char(@i) charac, isnumeric(char(@i)), TRY_CONVERT(int,char(@i))
    set @loop = @loop + 1
end

select * from @temp where isnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the line you are pointing !

This line is ok :

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(subScores.ScoreValue) = 1 THEN CAST(subScores.ScoreValue AS REAL) ELSE -1 END
```

But in the first case, just after the `WHERE` clause you have this line

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(subScores.ScoreValue) = 1 THEN CAST(subScores.ScoreValue AS REAL) ELSE subScores.ScoreValue END
```

It cannot work as if `ScoreValue` is not numeric, you have a case with real datas and varchar data (I guess `ScoreValue` is varchar)

You have to put once again `-1` instead of `ScoreValue` to make it work